# If Product Title Contains An Existing "Brand", Add As Attribute - Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, attributes, custom-wordpress-pages

We are looking for a way to automatically add a product attribute if the product title contains a value of an attribute, and the product attribute does not already exist.

The function we are looking for is as follows:

If 'post' does not contain *attribute*:

Then, if 'post_title' Contains 'pa_brand', 'pa_color', 'pa_size', 'pa_gender' add as *attribute*

Answer (score 1):

Get the product title and check if it contains desired string:

```
 $all_ids = get_posts( array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'fields' => 'ids'
));

foreach ( $all_ids as $id ) {

    $_product = wc_get_product( $id );
    $_sku = $_product->get_sku();
    $_title = $_product->get_title();

    //check if product title contains "pa_brand"
    if(strpos($_title, "pa_brand") != false)
    {
        //ADD PRODUCT ATTRIBUTE HERE
    }
}
```

To add product attribute kindly check: [Wordpress Woocommerce - use update_post_meta to add product attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23444319/wordpress-woocommerce-use-update-post-meta-to-add-product-attributes)

I hope this solution helps your problem. Have a good day.