# Woocommerce product attribute array has no values

Tags: woocommerce

When I try to get all product attributes they don't have any values.

```
$tmpBk = get_post_meta(10763, '_product_attributes',true);
print_r($tmpBk);
```

Response -

> Array ( [pa_brand] => Array ( [name] => pa_brand [value] => [position]
> => 1 [is_visible] => 1 [is_variation] => 0 [is_taxonomy] => 1 ) [pa_package-size] => Array ( [name] => pa_package-size [value] =>
> [position] => 2 [is_visible] => 1 [is_variation] => 1 [is_taxonomy] =>
> 1 ) [pa_volume] => Array ( [name] => pa_volume [value] => [position]
> => 3 [is_visible] => 1 [is_variation] => 0 [is_taxonomy] => 1 ) [pa_abv] => Array ( [name] => pa_abv [value] => [position] => 4
> [is_visible] => 1 [is_variation] => 0 [is_taxonomy] => 1 ) [pa_type-2]
> => Array ( [name] => pa_type-2 [value] => [position] => 6 [is_visible] => 1 [is_variation] => 0 [is_taxonomy] => 1 ) )

But It shows values in the backend & Frontend. Where are these values stored? & How do I add/update them programatically ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I hope I got your question right.

See [get meta data on on developer.wordpress.org](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/). In the user comments, there are some examples of how to get the values.

Additionally, WooCommerce installs some custom tables to store its data during install, see [woocommerce database description on github](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/Database-Description) - have a look in the tables `woocommerce_order_items` and `woocommerce_order_itemmeta`.

To add and update data, you can use

- `add_post_meta`, see [add_post_meta on developer.wordpress.org](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_post_meta/).
- `update_post_meta`, see [update_post_meta on developer.wordpress.org](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_post_meta/).

This [blog post](https://nicolamustone.blog/2017/03/01/post-meta-get-value/) which contains a good summary.

For the last part, I am not completely sure how I can answer how to add data programmatically. A good start for you could be this SO post about [updating post meta to add product attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23444319/wordpress-woocommerce-use-update-post-meta-to-add-product-attributes)